# Android: Difference between positive, negative, and neutral button

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

Is there a functional difference between positive, negative, and neutral buttons, particularly in the context of AlertDialogs?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just the position they take within the dialog...

- On devices prior to Honeycomb, the button order (left to right) was POSITIVE - NEUTRAL - NEGATIVE.
- On newer devices using the Holo theme, the button order (left to right) is now NEGATIVE - NEUTRAL - POSITIVE.

Comment: Take a note from http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html

The dismissive action of a dialog is always on the left. Dismissive actions return to the user to the previous state.
The affirmative actions are on the right. Affirmative actions continue progress toward the user goal that triggered the dialog.

So,it seems, that the neutral button should be on the edge anyway?

Comment: What happens if you put two neutrals, or two positives/negatives?

Comment: How do I get the neutral button?

Comment: In the Material design, they disregards from using more than one positive and one negative, moving away from 3 or more button options.  https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html

Answer (score 21):

On Lolipop and above or whenever you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` style, the buttons are arranged from left to right: Neutral, Negative and Positive.

Note: the Neutral button is always placed at the extreme left while the Negative and Positive buttons are packed together towards the right. [Took me awhile battling with this.]

[image: Material Design Dialog Button Placements]

Comment: That is not recomended by the material design guidelines. But I personally don't see any issue in the design. https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

Answer (score 14):

To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons):

> Note: You can only add one of each button type to the AlertDialog. That is, you cannot have more than one "positive" button. This limits the number of possible buttons to three: positive, neutral, and negative. These names are technically irrelevant to the actual functionality of your buttons, but should help you keep track of which one does what.

So it's entirely down to how you want to use it. It also influences order in a left-to-right sense (see Devunwired's answer for the ordering).

Comment: What happens if you put two neutrals, or two positives/negatives?

Answer (score 3):

As stated earlier, it defines the order, and you can have only one button of each kind. However the order I get (left to right) is Neutral, Negative, Positive both on a phone running Marshmallow and Android Studio emulator configured to Jelly Bean. I use AppCompat libs, so the behavior I observe may be typical for newer Android versions. Anyway it is not Negative, Neutral, Positive (i.e. not as it was stated earlier).

Answer (score 3):

According to Material Design Style Guide you shouldn't use neutral buttons anymore:

[Dialog specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs)

Comment: Are you sure? For example you can use Close button as a neutral, guess.

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko The above is just a guideline, so there can be exceptions. And the context for this is AlertDialogs. But using Close button as a neutral button smells like a UX issue.

Comment: what the way to use neutral button do you suggest?

Comment: I was thinking about cards. On cards you can use a third button, but then it's not a neutral button, because it's makes sense only in the context of a dialog. So there is no legit usage of neutral button I think. If there are more than one actions you should create a separate dialog for that. Close button in itself is not needed (back is enough). Otherwise Close is a negative action.