# How to make a edittext box in a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I am trying to make a edittext box in a dialog box for entering a password.
and when I am doing I am not able to do. I am a beginner in it.
Please help me in this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button create, show, setting;
//String pass="admin";String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.amcreate);
    setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.amsetting);
    show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.amshow);
    //input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.this);

    setting.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Create.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
        }

    });

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            // Creating alert Dialog with one Button
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            //AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("PASSWORD");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Password");
            **final EditText input = new EditText(this);**
            //alertDialog.setView(input);

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.key);

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Show.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
                        }
                    });
            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // closed

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    });
```

Image

[image]

I want to get as

[image]

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 alertDialog.setTitle("PASSWORD");
 alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Password");

 final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 input.setLayoutParams(lp);
 alertDialog.setView(input);
 alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.key);

 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             password = input.getText().toString();
             if (password.compareTo("") == 0) {
                 if (pass.equals(password)) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Password Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                         Show.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         }
     });

 alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             dialog.cancel();
         }
     });

 alertDialog.show();
 }

 });
```

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html. check positioning toasts. But i guess it's better to seterror for edittext

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Use Activtiy Context

Replace this

```
  final EditText input = new EditText(this);
```

By

```
  final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);  
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  input.setLayoutParams(lp);
  alertDialog.setView(input); // uncomment this line
```

Comment: public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
        dialog.cancel();

Comment: @Abhishek wher is your initialization. Like `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this)`. I think you copied your code from else where i guess

Comment: Sir, to be very true. I am a beginner.I just do research and then develop or implement. i basically understand some concepts.

Comment: sir dialog is being given as a dialoginterface. when any one clicks on  NO button it will get closed. should i use dialog.dismiss() ?

Comment: @Abhishek sorry my confusion it thought you had custom dialog . `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog` its the dialoginterface. using that is not a problem you click the negative button to dismiss the alertdialog.

Comment: Thanks for editing.. i was frustated with some user behaviour. they just vote down. otherwise i would have gain 20+

Comment: @Abhishek you are welcome glad to help but don't post those in question as it is irrelevant.

Comment: sir what can i do if i want to display a message on empty textbox or wrong password entered. i want to display it in the dialog box insted in toast. can i do?

Comment: @Abhishek display a toast message or set error for edittext. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747268/edittext-seterror-not-working-in-android

Comment: cant i display in the dialog only? toast is easy to do.but the toast gets display at the bottom only . can toast be displayed at the centre of screen?

Comment: @Abhishek you can use custom toast or set error to edittext. check the link posted in the above comment

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
         toast.show();  this worked for me to get the toast in centre.

Comment: Hi Raghu, If I want to put left margin & right margin to this edittext box then what should I write ? I tried many answers, to set margin programmatically, but nothing worked :(

Comment: Good suggestion of the asked topic, but a style comment is needed. 
Android is not Windows, and there is no need for a cancel button like it is a must in Win32, there is the OS "Back" button that serves as Cancel/No. 
So my suggestion is skipping the negative button on a password request dialog, and the positive button should not be "Yes" but should be "OK" (and get it localized by using android.R.string.ok). See more in my answer on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459827/how-can-i-set-the-order-of-the-positive-and-negative-buttons-in-alertdialog/53422599#53422599 topic.

Comment: The edit field should also be a one liner (edittext.setSingleLine();) in a password request (because it is) and that makes pressing enter on an attached physical (BT) keyboard (or a Chromebook) making the focus jump to the next item, the positive button. meaning that after entering the text, pushing enter twice the dialogue is positively ended.

Comment: setView() requires API level 21

Comment: how to give margin instead of matchParent in edit text ?

Answer (score 323):

I know its too late to answer this question but for others who are searching for some thing similar to this here is a simple code of an alertbox with an edittext

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

or

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.MyCustomDialogTheme);
```

if you want to change the theme of the dialog.

```
final EditText edittext = new EditText(ActivityContext);
alert.setMessage("Enter Your Message");
alert.setTitle("Enter Your Title");

alert.setView(edittext);

alert.setPositiveButton("Yes Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //What ever you want to do with the value
        Editable YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText();
        //OR
        String YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("No Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // what ever you want to do with No option.
    }
});

alert.show();
```

Comment: Where should I place this code? When i tried this in the method, and final field EditText placed on top of the class, it crashes.

Comment: what is the crash ?

Comment: Mine crashes too. It states that the edittext is null.

Comment: How to give margin to this EditText ?

Comment: Good suggestion of the asked topic, but a style comment is needed. Android is not Windows, and there is no need for a cancel button like it is a must in Win32, there is the OS "Back" button that serves as Cancel/No. So my suggestion is skipping the negative button on a password request dialog, and the positive button should not be "Yes" but should be "OK" (and get it localized by using android.R.string.ok). See more in my answer on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459827/how-can-i-set-the-order-of-the-positive-and-negative-buttons-in-alertdialog/53422599#53422599 topic.

Comment: The edit field should also be a one liner (edittext.setSingleLine();) in a password request (because it is) and that makes pressing enter on an attached physical (BT) keyboard (or a Chromebook) making the focus jump to the next item, the positive button. meaning that after entering the text, pushing enter twice the dialogue is positively ended.

Comment: Ah!  The key is the call `alert.setView()`!  And note that you can do this from a DialogBuilder as well.

Comment: @GhanshyamNayma it is not a margin but a padding might be enough: edittext.setPadding(30, 20, 30, 20)

Comment: How to change editText line color with this method ?

Answer (score 57):

Simplest of all would be.

- Create xml layout file for dialog . Add whatever view you want like
  EditText , ListView , Spinner etc.

  Inflate this view and set this to AlertDialog

Lets start with Layout file first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etComments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Enter comments(Optional)"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="8"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_file_created_above, null);
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Your Title Here");
alertDialog.setIcon("Icon id here");
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
Constant.alertDialog.setMessage("Your Message Here");


final EditText etComments = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etComments);
        
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});


alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alertDialog.dismiss()
    }
});

       
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: What a hero you are.

Comment: I crash. I found the reason I crashed was I missed the 'view' on the findViewById. Now I just need to know how to handle a check box so I can show or hide the password WHILE the dialog is still alive. Tried the multi item approach but it added its own check box in addition to the one in my layout!

Answer (score 33):

Simplified version

```
final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Add a new task")
        .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
        .setView(taskEditText)
        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                        null,
                        values,
                        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                db.close();
                updateUI();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create();
dialog.show();
return true;
```

Answer (score 12):

Try below code:

```
alert.setTitle(R.string.WtsOnYourMind);

 final EditText input = new EditText(context);
 input.setHeight(100);
 input.setWidth(340);
 input.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

 input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
 alert.setView(input);
```

Answer (score 10):

Setting margin in layout params will not work in Alertdialog. you have to set padding in parent layout and then add edittext in that layout.

This is my working kotlin code...

```
val alert =  AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)

val edittext = EditText(context!!)
edittext.hint = "Enter Name"
edittext.maxLines = 1

val layout = FrameLayout(context!!)

//set padding in parent layout
layout.setPaddingRelative(45,15,45,0)

alert.setTitle(title)

layout.addView(edittext)

alert.setView(layout)

alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_save), DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    dialog, which ->
    run {

        val qName = edittext.text.toString()

        Utility.hideKeyboard(context!!, dialogView!!)

    }

})
alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.label_cancel), DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

            dialog, which ->
            run {
                dismiss()
            }

})

alert.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! An answer that handles margin usage!

Answer (score 4):

You can also create custom alert dialog by creating an xml file.

dialoglayout.xml

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/dialog_txt_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
  </EditText>
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_login"
        android:background="@drawable/grey"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />
```

The Java Code:

```
@Override//to popup alert dialog
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
});


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogbuilder.setTitle("Title");
            dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
            dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
            break;
    }
    return dialogDetails;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
             final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
             Button loginbutton = (Button) alertDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
             Button cancelbutton = (Button) alertDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
             userName = (EditText) alertDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_name);
             loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      String name = userName.getText().toString();
                      Toast.makeText(Activity.this, name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             });
             cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                           alertDialog.dismiss();
                      }
             });
             break;
   }
}
```

Comment: this is what i needed but how can i use this in fragment its showing error

Answer (score 1):

Wasim's answer lead me in the right direction but I had to make some changes to get it working for my current project. 
I am using this function in a fragment and calling it on button click.

```
fun showPostDialog(title: String) {
        val alert =  AlertDialog.Builder(activity)

        val edittext = EditText(activity)
        edittext.hint = "Enter Name"
        edittext.maxLines = 1

        var layout = activity?.let { FrameLayout(it) }

        //set padding in parent layout
//        layout.isPaddingRelative(45,15,45,0)
        layout?.setPadding(45,15,45,0)

        alert.setTitle(title)

        layout?.addView(edittext)

        alert.setView(layout)

        alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_save), DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                dialog, which ->
            run {

                val qName = edittext.text.toString()

                showToast("Posted to leaderboard successfully")

                view?.hideKeyboard()

            }

        })
        alert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.label_cancel), DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                dialog, which ->
            run {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

        })

        alert.show()
    }

    fun View.hideKeyboard() {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    }

    fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

I hope it helps someone else in the near future. 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below code**

*`I created a Method like this`*

```
 public void getReferDialog(OnSubmitBtnClick submitBtnClick) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final View customLayout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dilog_refer_id, null);
    alertDialog.setView(customLayout);
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.ed_refer_user_input);
    Button submitBtn = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_refer_submit);
    TextView tvNo = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_thanks);
    TextView tvBody = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_refer_dialog_body);

    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String userText = editText.getText().toString();
        if (!userText.equals("")) {
            alert.dismiss();
            submitBtnClick.onClick(userText);
        }else {
            tvBody.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

    tvNo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        alert.dismiss();
        submitBtnClick.onClick("skip");
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

*`Here is my dilog_refer_id.xml file`*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_refer_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/refer_by_dialog_title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_refer_dialog_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_refer_dialog_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_regular"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/refer_by_dialog_body"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_refer_user_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_refer_dialog_body"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:autofillHints="FDCT4G"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text_refer"
        android:fontFamily="@font/seg_ui_semibold"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_refer_by"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_refer_submit"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ed_refer_user_input"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_thanks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_refer_submit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/drawer_item"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*`My bg_edit_text_refer.xml(drawable) file`*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/home_bg_extension"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

*`Creating a Interface for get user input data`*

```
public interface OnSubmitBtnClick {
    void onClick(String referId);
}
```

*`Finally all done now time to call it onclick method`*

```
showPopupBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        getReferDialog(new OnSubmitBtnClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(String referId) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, referId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Thank You, Happy Coding!!**

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin I done like this

```
private fun forgetPasswordDialog() {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_forgot_password, null)
        val etEmailAlert = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etEmailAlert)

        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.forgot_password))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.enter_your_email_address))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.send)) { dialog, _ ->
                if (etEmailAlert.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    etEmailAlert.error = getString(R.string.please_enter_email)
                    return@setPositiveButton
                } else {
                    sendResetPasswordEmail(etEmailAlert.text.toString()) {
                        if (it) {
                            runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Email sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.location_permission_button_negative)) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setView(view)
            .create()

        alertDialog.show()

    }
```

alert_forgot_password.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmailAlert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).