# How to pass data from an activity to dialog?

Tags: android-studio

How to pass data from an activity to dialog?

Refer to the image below for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a customized alert dialog .

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799216/how-to-make-a-edittext-box-in-a-dialog) for creation of customized alert dialog . 
According to your requirement , you need to add text view inside alert dialog with a boundary.

Even you can create a customized layout and set that inside alert dialog.

Passing Data from activity to dialog.Get data from activity , I assume it might be in string or integer format.
use setText() property of textview to pass data from string to textview which is inside alert dialog.