# ConstraintLayout in Cardview adding white space

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a `CardView` that has a `ConstraintLayout` to organize some `TextView`.

Sometimes it'll display as intended, but sometimes, it'll add extra white space such as when a keyboard is closed and ruin the layout. I have a GIF below showing the `CardView` working and not working in the same span of time.

[image: ConstraintLayout adding white space]

A code snippet for the relevant `CardView` is below. I use `wrap_content` to try to keep the `CardView` at the size I want, but it still expands.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView_game_cash"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:contentPadding="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_cashLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Cash"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_totalProfitLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Profit"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_game_totalProfit"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView_game_totalProfit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_profitLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Win Profit"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_game_profit"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView_game_profit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_game_totalProfit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_game_cashLabel"
            tools:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_totalProfit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_game_profit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            tools:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_game_profit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView_game_totalProfit"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_game_cash"
            tools:text="TextView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: add inside manifest activity tag:             android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|navigation"

Comment: I added those flags. It still does not work as intended.

Comment: create edittext in alertdialog like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799216/how-to-make-a-edittext-box-in-a-dialog

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of using `wrap_content` in the `textView`, I used `android:layout_height="0dp"` along with `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"`

Comment: Thank you @Jaydeep. The configChanges line helped me debug the problem more easily.

Comment: welcome always Happy to Help

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved my hours

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In the `TextView` within the `ConstraintLayout`, I replaced `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

with:

`android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"`

The layout worked as intended with that change to all the `TextView` within.

Comment: app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap" is depricated. now you can just add app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" to every view that use wrap_content height