# Custom AlertDialog with EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I try to developp a little android application and show a dialog alert with just a edittext to fill  custom
as the next link

[Creating a custom layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)
I have this code but it doesn't work

```
public class TraceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


TraceDialogListener mListener;

public interface TraceDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_trace, null))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_locate)
            .setTitle(R.string.trace_title)
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(TraceDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(TraceDialogFragment.this);
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try{
        mListener = (TraceDialogListener) context;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement TraceDialogListener");
    }
}
```

}

but the code run in a loop on

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

I don't understand

In my class main activity

I have this code

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TraceDialogFragment.TraceDialogListener

DialogFragment traceDialog = new TraceDialogFragment();
traceDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"TraceDialogFragment");
```

Here my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

and my logcat is the next

```
11-07 11:10:50.015 23570-23570/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: , PID: 23570
                                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799216/how-to-make-a-edittext-box-in-a-dialog

Comment: The code looks fine at first sight. What do you mean by 'run in a loop'? Does the app crash? If so, post your logcat output.

Comment: I have this log java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: and this public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TraceDialogFragment.TraceDialogListener

Comment: If I debug it stay on this 2 lines and back and go

Answer (score 2):

## Try this one for AlertDialogue with editText

- Just call this `method` in your `Activity or Fragment` in `Oncreate or OnCreateView`

  ```
   public void inflateDialogue() {
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater=SelectUsers.this.getLayoutInflater();
      final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_group_name, null);
      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle("Group_name");

      alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

      edt_groupName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_groupName);

      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              str_getTextFrom=edt_groupName.getText().toString();
              //here we have to call Database firebase

              dialog.dismiss();

          }
      });
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss();
          }
      });
      alertDialog.setView(view);
      alertDialog.show();
  }
  ```

---

- create `dialog_group_name` in your `xml`

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edt_groupName"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10dp"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10dp"
      android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
      android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
      android:hint="@string/enter_groupName"
      android:inputType="textCapWords"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem with change my namespace

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; 
to 
import android.app.AlertDialog;

I don't understand everything .... but it works