# Does Material Components provide edit text dialog when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

I need a edit text dialog when I use Jetpack Compose in my project.

The Code A is from the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799216/how-to-make-a-edittext-box-in-a-dialog).

**Q1:**  I don't know if Code A can use in Jetpack Compose, could you tell me?

I was told that Dialogs are available in the [Material library](https://material.io/components/dialogs/android) for Jetpack Compose

It seems that Material library only provide Alert dialog, Simple dialog and Confirmation dialog.

**Q2:** Does Material Components provide edit text dialog when I use Jetpack Compose?

**Code A**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

final EditText edittext = new EditText(ActivityContext);
alert.setMessage("Enter Your Message");
alert.setTitle("Enter Your Title");

alert.setView(edittext);

alert.setPositiveButton("Yes Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //What ever you want to do with the value
        Editable YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText();
        //OR
        String YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("No Option", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // what ever you want to do with No option.
    }
});

alert.show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AlertDialog implementation from Jetpack Compose allows you to add title, buttons and text as a content.

If you want to add an EditText (or, more preciesly, TextField) instead of just text, you may create your own layout for dialog like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyAlertDialog(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dismissButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    confirmButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(onDismiss) {
        Surface(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium) {
            Column {
                Column(Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
                    title.invoke()
                    Spacer(Modifier.size(16.dp))
                    content.invoke()
                }
                Spacer(Modifier.size(4.dp))
                Row(
                    Modifier.padding(8.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                    Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.End),
                ) {
                    dismissButton.invoke()
                    confirmButton.invoke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you call this composable function with [OutlinedTextField](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)) as a content, result will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

You can see full working demo [here](https://github.com/sirekanian/q73020785/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sirekanian/so/q73020785/MainActivity.kt).